# How to fix never ending runtimes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

So I have three seperate function in MATLAB where each have its designated purpose.

1. The first one calculates the partial derivative
2. The second finds the roots for a system of two equations and two variables.
3. The third is supposed to find the critical point.

I have tried doing everything separately and it worked. However when I do this through my CriticalPoint function it just keeps running(it says "busy" in the lower left corner).

I have tried solving this manually. Meaning that I've used each function as intended, saved the values in my workspace and used for the next function.

The only thing different is how I treated my partials.

I have a function which takes evaluates the partial derivative at a point [x,y].

```
 derivative = Pderiv(f, a, b, i) 

%The i denotes if the partial derivative is take with respect to x or y
%where if i == 1, then it means that partial derivative is with respect to
%x and if i == 2 then  it is with respect to y
```

The thing I did differently was that I found the partial derivative for f(x,y) manually using pen and paper.

I.e

df/dx and df/dy  (these are partials, sorry for not using the proper symbol)

And then I inserted it into my function:

```
[x0,y0] = MyNewton(f, g, a, b)
```

Where df/dx is the argument for "f" and df/dy is the argument for "g".

This gives me the correct x & y values when  df/dx=df/dy=0.

What I want to have it do is for a given function f(x,y)

I want to find the partial derivative where the input values are still represented by x and y.

I was told by my teacher that  the following expression:

```
g=@(x,y)NPderiv(f,x,y,1);
```

would be sufficent. Is it though? Since it works when I do it manually but the program runs forever when I define my function g as above.

I'm not sure if it is relevant but here is my code for the partial derivative:

```
function derivative = NPderiv(f, a, b, i)

h = 0.0000001;
fn=zeros(1,2);

if i == 1
fn(i) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b))/h;


elseif i==2

    fn(i) = (f(a,b+h)-f(a,b))/h;

end

derivative = fn(i);

end
```

function for my critical point function:

```
function [x,y] = CriticalPoint(f, a, b)

g=@(x,y)NPderiv(f,x,y,1); %partial derivative for f(x,y) with respect to x
z=@(x,y)NPderiv(f,x,y,2);%partial derivative for f(x,y) with respect to y


[x,y]=MyNewton(g,z,a,b);




end
```

MyNewton function:

```
function [x0,y0] = MyNewton(f, g, a, b)

y0 = b; 
x0 = a;

tol = 1e-18;

resf = tol + 1; 
resg = tol + 1;

 while  resf > tol && resg > tol

  dfdx = NPderiv(f, x0, y0, 1);  
  dfdy = NPderiv(f, x0, y0, 2);
  dgdx = NPderiv(g, x0, y0, 1);
  dgdy = NPderiv(g, x0, y0, 2);

  jf1 = [f(x0,y0) dfdy; ...
       g(x0,y0) dgdy];

  jg1 = [dfdx f(x0,y0); ...
        dgdx g(x0,y0)]; 

  j2 = [dfdx dfdy; ...
        dgdx dgdy];

  jx = det(jf1)./det(j2); 
  jy = det(jg1)./det(j2); 

  x0 = x0 - jx; 
  y0 = y0 - jy;

  resf = abs(f(x0,y0));
  resg = abs(g(x0,y0));
end
end
```

Comment: Show the MyNewton function.

Comment: @maximus it has now been added.

Comment: Aren't you taking sort of second derivative inside of MyNewton function ? Is that what you wanted to do? (assuming MyNPderiv is same as NPderiv)

Comment: @maximus They are the same. It is now fixed. It would be taking the second derivative for elements in the j matrices. 

Take the function f(x,y) = (x-1)^2 +(y-1)^2 ) as a example. 

Since I want to treat both partials as separte functions f & g which I can use for MyNewton.

I would think that:

    g=@(x,y)MyNPderiv(f,x,y,1); 

Would be treated the same as df/dx = 2x-2

Comment: how about increasing tolerance?

Comment: @maximus decreasing it to 0.001 worked... I've no idea how? What? But it is very inconsistent and gives me answers close to the critical point

Comment: @maximus so the problem seems to be with my partial derivative. I don't know why it ceases to work for larger values for the tolerance. I am very confounded

Comment: Could you try rewriting using diff / eval and "syms x, y real ". Sorry can't test it doesn't have matlab right now with me

Comment: @maximus unfortunately not since it was part of the task to write a code for the partial derivative. It is truly bewildering and I am curious why lowering the tolerance to 0.01 gives me approximations close to the real value(not close enough however) and a larger tolerance gives me the output NaN or it  keeps running forever.

Comment: well NAN most probably is coming from dertivative of j2 equal to zero. maybe method diverges. also could you try increasing h value in NPderiv? With the tolerance 1e-18 as before.

Comment: @maximus  when I call NPderiv(f,0,0,1) I get 0 which is wrong. It's supposed to be -2. When I call 

    [x,y]= CriticalPoint(f, 0, 0). 

I get x = NaN and y = NaN

When 

    h = 1e-18;

Comment: Try to set precision. It might be an issue. You set it to 1e-18 but I guess max precision used is 1e-16. Could you make it lower and set precision using digits(d). Anyway why you need such precision as 1e-18?

Comment: Sorry, by lower I mean higher (not 1e-18 but for example 1e-12)

Comment: @maximus I will try that. However, why do you think my NPderiv(f,a,b,i) "breaks" when setting h to values closer to zero?

Comment: The precision of matlab by default might be higher than the one you set. So it might never reach that precision.